# Setting a type on specific property of a mapped type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type in TypeScript for something we are converting over from JavaScript.

Basically the type is a standard object literal where each child is a repeat of the same type. However if its the '_errors' property this should be an array of another type and is optional.

Is this possible in TypeScript?

This is sort of what I'm after but the syntax below is invalid.

```
// This is invalid but might demonstrate what I'm after...
type MyType = { 
    _errors?: ErrorWrapper[]; // Anything using the key '_errors' should be an array of ErrorWrapper. But this should be optional.
    [key: string]: MyType; // Any other properties should be MyType.
 };

interface ErrorWrapper {
    message: string;
    mapped: boolean;
}
```

In JavaScript the object looked like this:

```
let myObject = {
  property1: {
    property1a: {
       _errors: [{
          message: 'string message',
          mapped: false
       },{
          message: 'string message',
          mapped: false
       }]
    },
    property1b: {
       _errors: [{
          message: 'string message',
          mapped: false
      }]
    }
  },
  property2: {
       _errors: [{
          message: 'string message',
          mapped: false
      }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong but I don't think this is possible today. I tried with:

```
interface ErrorWrapper {
    message: string;
    mapped: boolean;
}

type ErrorMap<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Partial<{ _errors: ErrorWrapper[] }> & ErrorMap<(Partial<T[P]>)>;
};

interface SomeObj {
    property1: {
        property1a: number;
        property1b: string;
    };
    property2: number;
}

declare let x: ErrorMap<SomeObj> ;

// Autocomplete works as expected
console.log(x.property1.property1a._errors);
console.log(x.property1.property1b._errors);
console.log(x.property2._errors);

// Error
let myObject: ErrorMap<SomeObj> =  {
  property1: {
    property1a: {
       _errors: [{
          message: "string message",
          mapped: false
       }, {
          message: "string message",
          mapped: false
       }]
    },
    property1b: {
       _errors: [{
          message: "string message",
          mapped: false
      }]
    }
  },
  property2: {
    _errors: [{
        message: "string message",
        mapped: false
    }]
  }
};
```

I think we need a conditional in the mapped type but [that feature is not available yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833).